# Trouble with UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm totally stuck with the UIPickerView. I keep getting the error :

GDB: received signal: "SIGABRT".

2011-07-14 13:35:19.132 MeldStad[677:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaac34c0'

I've read some solution on internet but none of them worked for me..
I've also tried more than 1 PickerView tutorial. Don't know what to do know.

Here is the source of the picker methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:
(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: How have you set the delegate and where have you added these methods?

Comment: ok i think the connections are good now. I followed this tutorial for connections (step 6). http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html The error is gone, but when i try to retrieve the selected item by clicking on a button, i don't get anything back.                                               NSInteger row = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
 NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
 NSLog(@"test:", selected);

Comment: `singlePicker` must be `nil` i.e. not connected in IB. Check that.

Comment: thnx alot for your help, it works now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is saying that you setup your UIPicker delegate in the IB to the UIView where you don't have UIPickerDelegate methods

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

Or you assigned your delegates to a wrong file. Check IB connection settings. Your datasource and delegate should be set to FilesOwner

Comment: ok i think the connections are good now. I followed this tutorial for connections (step 6).http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html The error is gone, but when i try to retrieve the selected item by clicking on a button, i don't get anything back. NSInteger row = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]; NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row]; NSLog(@"test:", selected);